# how do you pronounce perfume(s)?

Tags: pronunciation

A poem from Whitman (song of myself, 2) uses the word *perfume* and also *perfumes*.

Both in different videos on the web or google translate pronounce *perfume* and *perfumes* in different way. Frequently the accent is in **fu** when pronouncing perfume, an in **per** when pronouncing perfumes. This seems to me the correct way, but I've found some videos with different pronunciation.

Is it correct? Is there a simple rule for pronunciation in those cases?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the dictionary pronunciations you've checked?

Comment: The syllable emphasis of the first "perfumes" in the first stanza is affected slightly by the meter of the poetry.  Otherwise I detect no difference.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GX7ssynVkg4

Comment: It is important to note that how *I* pronounce it and how someone from another region of the world may pronounce it could very different, but neither one wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The accent isn’t expected to change based on the presence of the suffix *-s.* Either accentuation is possible, but for people who use both pronunciations, the most likely distinction would be initial stress for the noun vs. second-syllable stress for the verb.

That pattern (initial stress for the noun, and second/final-syllable stress for the verb) is used for a number of other disyllabic words—mostly ones that are formed from a prefix plus a monosyllabic root, such as *insult* and *progress.* But it isn't regular enough to count as a "simple rule": there are also words that are pronounced with only one stress pattern for both noun and verb uses, such as *reˈport, supˈport, conˈcern, deˈbate, diˈstress* or *ˈdeluge, ˈedit, ˈoffer.*